# Approaches to distance and time linear systems

Tags: linear-algebra

For a question such as "Two cars going south and north are $35$ km apart and will meet in 1 hour and $30$ minutes. If both cars were going north, still 35 km apart, the faster car would meet the slower car $5$ hours and $30$ minutes later." What would be an approach to model this situation? So far, I've come up with:

$$x+y=35\\
x+35=y$$

Would this be an acceptable approach even though $x$ would be a negative km/h?

Comment: Your two equations don't see, to model the situation. what are x an y, you tak of x,y as speed, but you add them to be a distance,  if x and y are the speeds you have to use the given times , to get a speed.

Answer (score 1):

Say the faster car travels and speed $x$, and the slower one at speed $y$. you are given that in $1.5$ hours they cover a combined distance of $35$ km, meaning (since $\text{speed} \times \text{time} = \text{distance}$)

$$1.5x+1.5y=35 \implies x+y = \frac{70}{3}$$

The next scenario is a bit more complex, but can still be dealt with without additional variables. In $5.5$ hours, the faster car traveled precisely $35$ km more than the slower one (think about it: it started $35$ km behind, and $5.5$ hours later it catches up). Mathematically, this can be expressed by:

$$5.5x -35 = 5.5y \implies x-y = \frac{70}{11}$$

It is generally important in these problems to notice exactly what each variable represents, and to try sketching what is happening. As I did here, choosing velocities as the variables is often useful, but this may change to times or distances, depending on the problem at hand.

Comment: @ HappyDay It is not use to give complete answers to homework questions

Comment: Sorry, I thought that an attempt allowed for an answer. Should I delete the answer?

Comment: The attempt can be corrected, but since it is here, just leave it.

Comment: This is a problem I made up myself when I was bored, it’s not related to homework.